# Timestamp to get current time/date

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

I need simple code using PHP to get the current date/time using TIMESTAMP and insert this into a database.

I have a field called "ArrivalTime" within a database as TIMESTAMP.

EDIT:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("a&e", $con) or die('Could not select database.');
```

// validate

```
$time = time(); $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$time);

$sql="INSERT INTO Patient(Forename, Surname, Gender, Date_Of_Birth, Address,    Patient_History, Illness, Priority, Arrival_Time)
VALUES('$patient_name', '$patient_lastname', '$gender', '$date', '$address', '$history', '$illness', '$priority', '$time')";
mysql_query($sql,$con) or die('Error: ' . mysql_error());

echo "1 record added";
// close connection 
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**main.php**

```
<?php
    require('connect.php');

    $time = time();


    $sql = "INSERT INTO yourtablename (ArrivalTime) Values ('$time')";
    mysql_query($sql);

    ?>
```

P.S: in the sql statement i'm sure you'll need to put other things in the other fields ,so you just replace the one above by this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO yourtablename (field1, field2, ArrivalTime) Values ('$value1','$value2','$time')";
```

**connect.php**

```
<?php

$error = "Couldn't connect";
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password") or die($error);
mysql_select_db("yourdatabase") or die($error);

?>
```

Comment: That's great, many thanks. Will I need to incorporate php into my form as a hidden string to echo the time into the database?

Comment: it depends what do you intend to do exactly? Are you using html to post values?

Comment: those are 2 separate files: main.php and connect.php, you place them in the same folder as your `html` file.

Comment: I need the exact arrival time/date of a patient. The form is to collect patient information and store it in the database. I have used POST functionality to post the patient values for example: Forename into the database. Do I need to do this for the time? (I don't want the time to display on the form, only the database)

Comment: the time will not display on the form, just remove the echo. I'll edit it

Comment: the current values inserting into the database are 0

Comment: check everything. make sure they are correct because i'm sure the code I provided works 100%. Can you  copy your code into your question so i can help more?

Comment: you didn't call `time()`. Add those 2 lines:`$time = time();` `$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$time);`

Comment: Ive edited in the question with your example, is this correct?

Comment: still displaying 0 format in database, even though code is correct, frustrating!

Comment: make sure of the type of the field. don't put the timestamp as date. put it as integer. and the date put it as string. I mean change the field's type in mysql to `int` in Arrival_Time

Comment: In the database, the Arrival_Time is set to timestamp and default is "current timestamp"

Comment: changing arrival_time to int made the values display as "1363811452"

Comment: default must be none. Since it's not mysql giving you the timestamp, we chose php and you're inserting the value as integer from php.

Comment: Yes this is timestamp. Timestamp is the number of seconds since 1/1/1970 till now. I suggest that you make another field called datetime having a type of `Text`. Insert into this field $date instead of $time because it is the parsed Datetime. Try it on your own and if you have any problem i'll help you later i need to study for my exam:p take care! :)

Comment: Okay, I need the timestamp function then for current time/date. Sorry!

Answer (score 3):

The query will be:

```
 INSERT INTO mytable(ArrivalTime) VALUES(UNIX_TIMESTAMP())
```

Answer (score 1):

mysql has a function [UNIX_TIMESTAMP()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) for getting a Unix timestamp as an unsigned integer.

Example:

mysql> SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
    -> 1196440210

So you can use this sql query:

insert into tableName(ArrivalTime) values(UNIX_TIMESTAMP())