# Show current_timestamp in PHP

Tags: php, postgresql

I inserted `current_timestamp` in a PostgreSQL database. I want to show the date and time in a PHP program but nothing I do shows the time.

I used - `$date = date("m-d-Y h-i-s", strtotime($row['status_date']));`

The date is OK, but the time always shows as 12-00-00.

Comment: Can you show us what is the value of $row['status_date'] ?

Comment: you may mistook, when you insert. Check that code otherwise post that too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Timestamp to get current time/date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15533060/timestamp-to-get-current-time-date)

Comment: $row['status_date'] shows 10-04-2013 12:00:00.

Answer (score 1):

If you have php5.4, you can run this script:

```
<?php echo (new DateTime())->getTimestamp();
```

And if you have stored date time in database:

```
<?php echo (new DateTime($row['status_date']))->getTimestamp();
```

In PHP5.4 has ben added class member access on instantiation. In older version of php we need two steps:

```
<?php
    $date = new DateTime();
    echo $date->getTimestamp();
```

Comment: echo (new DateTime())->getTimestamp(); throws an error. Expecting `',".

Comment: Which version of php do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Possible that the **$row['status_date']** has no time on it. Possible output of **$row['status_date']** is 2013-10-04 00:00:00. You can try this:

```
$date = date("m-d-Y h:i A", strtotime($row['status_date']));
```

Comment: Result is 10-04-2013 12:00 AM.